# Why do we prefer subnet 192.168.1.0/24 to get more networks? Why not just make 192.168.2.0/24 another network and 192.168.3.0/24 another one

Tags: networking, subnet

Why do we prefer subnet `192.168.1.0/24` to get more networks?
--network #1 `192.168.1.0/25`    #2  `192.168.1.128/25`

Why not just make `192.168.2.0/24` another network and `192.168.3.0/24` another one. Does it work? What is the difference? Pros and cons?

Comment: Because `192.168.2.0/24` isn't valid.

Comment: @user207421 huh?

Comment: I currently run a network like that. Mostly its cause your consumer routers and other CPEs tend to have those as a default.

Comment: Who is "we"? I certainly don't. I prefer /27s within 172.16.0.0/12.

Answer (score 3):

> Why do we prefer subnet 192.168.1.0/24 to get more networks? --network #1 192.168.1.0/25 #2 192.168.1.128/25

I have not seen anyone else say that this is "preferred".

There is no specific reason for it to be preferred, either, assuming that the other /24's are available for use.

> Why not just make 192.168.2.0/24 another network and 192.168.3.0/24 another one. Does it work? What is the difference? Pros and cons?

It does work, and it was in fact the original design back in the "classful routing" days – the reserved range of 192.168.0.0/16 used to be called "256 class-C networks", aka 256 /24's.

(These days, of course, you're not restricted to them being /24's; you can divide the reserved /16 into any size you need, whether it's /25's or /22's or /19's.)

Comment: In fact, Private Address Space was defined _after_ CIDR, and RFC 1918 makes reference to pre-CIDR nomenclature, but calls the ranges by number of host bits: "_We will refer to the first block as '24-bit block', the second as '20-bit block', and to the third as '16-bit' block. Note that (in pre-CIDR notation) the first block is nothing but a single class A network number, while the second block is a set of 16 contiguous class B network numbers, and third block is a set of 256 contiguous class C network numbers._"

Comment: @RonMaupin: RFC 1918 is not the original definition – it's an update to RFC 1597, which did not have the "(in pre-CIDR notation)" part yet, and talked entirely about classes and host-bits. While it technically post-dates CIDR as defined in RFC 1518 by around half a year, presumably that was still too new to be adopted when RFC 1597 was being written (given that it still has notes about "if subnetting is a problem..." and subnetting wasn't even new at that time).

Comment: My point is that Private address space was defined after CIDR, and the current RFC for it only references classes in passing, having named the three ranges. Network address classes were deprecated two years _before_ the commercial Internet, and  the current RFC 1918 was the next year after the commercial Internet., meaning that Private address space does not follow address classes that have not even be in use this century.

Answer (score 1):

It is widely used because it's the "first" address that comes to mind for a new network (and it's somewhat in the head of most tech persons as a default setting for new devices). But there is no real preference for using `192.168.1.0/24`. In fact, I would avoid it because it might bring trouble if you connect via VPN (IP conflict) since it's so widely used.

Essentially you can use whatever you want, I prefer three-digit networks: e.g. `192.168.100.100`. Sometimes (e.g. the Windows IP setting until Windows 10) the input mask jumps over to the next number block automatically, once you fill in the three digits, if you have less than three digits you have to move over to the next block manually.

Note, that you can't make it bigger by using multiple /24 networks without a router. To add more IPs to your range use a smaller subnet mask e.g. /16 for 65.534 instead of 254 hosts.

Comment: If you press ‘.’ the cursor moves to the next octet too.

Comment: @GregW thanks for the tip!